# Android Room observable query not triggering second time with viewmodel

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

Spent the last 10 hours searching for a solution to my problem, but I am not able to understand what exactly is the problem and it's driving me crazy.

I have a `viewmodel` where on `init` I am collecting a `flow` like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            taxCalendarUseCase
                .observeCalendarBetweenDates(
                    startDate = uiState.selectedMonth.value.atDay(1),
                    endDate = uiState.selectedMonth.value.atEndOfMonth()
                )
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .collect { list ->
                    Timber.i("Collect is called with ${list.size} items")
                    uiState.taxCalendar.value = list
                    uiState.selectedCountry.value =
                        uiState.taxCalendar.value.map { it.countryCode }.distinct().firstOrNull()
                            ?: ""
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And my `DAO` looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface TaxCalendarDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM tax_calendar WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end")
    fun observeTaxCalendarListBetweenDates(start: String, end: String): Flow<List<TaxCalendarModel>>
}
```

Based on the log I've put in the `collect` block, when I open my `Composable` the first time it's called (This is screen A), then going to another `Composable` (Screen B) where I add some data to the database, when navigating up I expect `collect` being called again but this is not happening.

Edit1: I've tried to change the dispatcher, to add `onEach`, to remove `distinctUntillChanged` to make a `mutableStateFlow` and collecting in the `repository`

Comment: Could the problem be the navigateup? Maybe hilt doesnt create another instance of viewmodel. Does the init block work when it comes back to screen B?

Comment: The viewmodel is not destroyed, it's one of the things I've tried yesterday. When I popbackstack without keeping the Screen A indeed it's working, but this is not the right behavior. The viewmodel should collect the new added value even when the composable is not visible to the screen

Comment: That's because the VMs scope is tied to the NavBackStackEntry (of the NavController/NavHost). So until a screen persists in the navigation stack the VMs init block won't be called again, i.e. the same VM instance is being returned for the same composable until its NavBackStackEntry is gone. However the NavHost -> NavGraph composable block is called again on navigateUp (also on popBackStack) so what you can do is move your logic into a function in you VM, and call that function inside a SideEffect (as far up the composable chain as possible), i.e. on every full recomposition of your screen A.

Comment: I tested this a bit and the SideEffect will be called too often, so you can use the LaunchedEffect(Unit) { } instead. If you update your answer with your navigation part where the screen A is composed, I can write an answer for this.